# Row gets unselected list swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

```swift
List(viewModel.surahs, selection: $selected) { surah in
    Button {
        selected = surah.id
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Text(surah.name.transliteration.en)
            Spacer()
            Text(surah.name.short)
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
```

This is my list in SwiftUI.

- **What I want:** When user taps on a row the row stays highlighted.
- **But what I get:** On each tap the row gets selected and unselected within a fraction of seconds.
- **One more thing:** If I add or subtract 1 with `surah.id` in line no 3, upon tapping on a row the next or previous row stays selected. (I mean when I use `selected = surah.id + 1` or `selected = surah.id - 1` instead of `selected = surah.id`

Comment: Why do you have a button, why don't you let `List` handle the selection and updating of the `selected` property?

Comment: in other words, remove the `Button` and keep only the `HStack{...}`, the `List` does it all for you.

Comment: Your solution works thanks. But I have to trigger a function with the property of the surah. That's why I have used the button inside.

Comment: if you want to do something when you select a row, attach `.onChange(of: selected) {...}` to the `List`.

Comment: I could use onTapGesture on the HStack but It would only trigger if I would speciafically tap on the views inside HStack and not the whole row.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks your idea is actually clean. But there is a small catch. onChange selected I will have the value of selected. But I wanted the specific refenece of surah. I understand that I can use the selected as the index number of surahs then access the specific surah.

Comment: Then the SurahModel needs to conform to hashable.

Comment: yes, SurahModel needs to conform to hashable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you describe and trigger a function when you select a row, attach `.onChange(of: selected) {...}` to the `List`.

For example:

```
 List(surahs, selection: $selected){ surah in
     HStack{
         Text(surah.name.transliteration.en)
         Spacer()
         Text(surah.name.short)
     }
 }
 .onChange(of: selected) {
     print("-----> do something here")
     // if selected ... else ....
 }
 .listStyle(.plain)
```

Comment: thanks your idea is actually clean. But there is a small catch. onChange selected I will have the value of selected. But I wanted the specific refenece of surah. I understand that I can use the selected as the index number of surahs then access the specific surah.

Comment: in that case make `selected` of type of `surah` instead of type `id`. With this you will have to add `.tag(surah)` to the `HStack`. Or use the `id` to get the corresponding surah.